# ANOVA Type II vs Type III SSq for multiple factors

Tags: anova, sums-of-squares

I have pondered type II vs type III sums of squares for some time and looked at posted examples of calculations for 2 main factors (e.g. [this very nice page](https://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/)). That is, in the case of a model:

X = A + B

**Type II**:
Factor A: SSq (A|B)
Factor B: SSq (B|A)

**Type III**:
Factor A: SSq (A|B,AB)
Factor B: SSq (B|A,AB)

Without wanting to stir the hornet's nest (i.e. my desire is not to fuel the war between TII vs TIII), my "simple" interpretation would be that it seems fortuitous to use TII when there are indications that interactions between A & B are not significant/relevant, whereas when/if interactions account for a large portion of systematic variability (i.e. large SSq(AB) or significant AB interaction), TIII may offer benefits.

BUT, let's say I have a model looking like this:

X = A + B + AB + C

Am I correct to assume that:

**Type II**:
Factor A: SSq (A|B,AB,C)
Factor B: SSq (B|A,AB,C)
Factor AB: SSq (AB|A,B,C)
Factor C: SSq (C|A,AB,B)

Moreover, what happens with the interaction terms for calculating TIII SSq? According to my understanding of adjusting for interaction SSq terms, this would produce monstrocities, such as:

**Type III**:
Factor A: SSq (A|B,AB,C,BC,ABC)
... etc

I've omitted the term BAB, since I fail to see how it could be relevant (but I've been wrong before).

In addition to the actual calculation of TIII SSq for multiple factors - Would they even make sense for multiple factors and high-order interactions such as ABC?